# PowerShell gc missing parenthesis

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a script in batch, which calls a powershell gc command, and I'm not being able to fix it.

That's the actual script:

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\test\run.bat') -replace '_installdir_', 'C:\Program Files\MySoftware'| Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\test\run.bat"
```

So my script simply change the word *installdir* to another string (C:\Program....) inside the file specified in my `gc` (since it's the same in the output).

It works perfectly, but when I try to make it generic to reuse, I've done this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc '%1%') -replace '%2%', '%3%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %1%"
```

Whenever I execute it, no matter what I passed as args, I've got this problem:

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\test\run.bat231"
The string is missing the terminator: '.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

My first parameter in this case was `C:\test\run.bat`, the same that I was using in the previous version.
I've called like this:

```
myscript.bat C:\test\run.bat aa bb
```

Obs.: I've put nonsense args in the second and third to isolate the problem in the first one.

But I have no idea why its not working, neither from where it takes this "231" in the end.

Comment: You can use `%InstallDir%` in your BAT and work with an environment variable. Is there a special reason why that's not an option?

Comment: What is `%1%` etc?? Do you mean `%1` `%2` and `%3`?

Comment: Positional parameters in batch are `%1`, `%2`, etc., not `%1%`, `%2%`, etc.

Comment: Additionally, to understand it better, I suggest opening `cmd` and running `call /?` that will help you understand arguments as well as how to expand on them

Comment: As the powershell part properly (single) quotes the passed arguments you should remove possible double quotes from arguments with the `~` modifier. `powershell -Command "(gc '%~1') -replace '%~2', '%~3' | Out-File -encoding ASCII '%~1'"` Otherwise inner double quotes will pair with the outer double quotes unbalanced.

Comment: Thank you all, the second % was the real problem.
You guys rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postitional parameters in batch don't have a trailing `%`. It's just `%1`, `%2`, ... instead of `%1%`, `%2%`, ... used for variables. Because of that the trailing `%` in `%1%` is interpreted as the first `%` in a (curiously named) variable `%') -replace '%`, which is undefined. Same goes for the trailing `%` in `%2%` and `%3%`.

```
"(gc '%1%') -replace '%2%', '%3%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %1%"
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       ^      ^                               ^
```

In the above string `%1` is expanded to the first positional parameter (in your case apparently `C:\test\run.bat`), while the "variables" `%') -replace '%`, `%', '%`, and `%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %` are expanded to empty strings, leaving just the numbers indicated by the `^` in the above schematic.

Remove the trailing `%` from the positional parameters to resolve this issue (you may also want to add a `~` to have outer double quotes from the arguments):

```
"(gc '%~1') -replace '%~2', '%~3' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %~1"
```